# Compute Engine: URLFetch is not available in this environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am trying to put a python server in a VM on Google Compute Engine that its duration is more than 10 minutes (time limit in App Engine for a service). I give you my code and the output:

```
from google.cloud import storage as gcs
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
appengine.monkeypatch()

def my_function(filename, stringdata):

   # init client gcp
   gcs_client = gcs.Client()
   bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket(config["cloud_storage_segment"])
   upload_blob_from_string(bucket, filename, stringdata)
```

The output says me this:

> File
>   "/home/guillermo.diaz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1994, in **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1985, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.handle_exception(e)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1540, in handle_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1982, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1517, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1598, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>
> File "/home/user/my_module/main.py",
>   line 50, in my_function
>       bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket(config["cloud_storage_segment"])
>
> File
>   "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py",
>   line 225, in get_bucket
>       bucket.reload(client=self)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py",
>   line 108, in reload
>       _target_object=self)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py",
>   line 290, in api_request
>       headers=headers, target_object=_target_object)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py",
>   line 183, in _make_request
>       return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)   File
>   "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py",
>   line 211, in _do_request
>       return self.http.request(
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py",
>   line 73, in http
>       return self._client._http
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py",
>   line 151, in _http
>       self._credentials))
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py",
>   line 161, in **init**
>       super(AuthorizedSession, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 396, in **init**
>       self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter())
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_toolbelt/adapters/appengine.py",
>   line 79, in **init**
>       super(AppEngineAdapter, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_toolbelt/adapters/appengine.py",
>   line 60, in **init**
>       super(AppEngineMROHack, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 127, in **init**
>       self.init_poolmanager(pool_connections, pool_maxsize, block=pool_block)
>
> File
>   "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_toolbelt/adapters/appengine.py",
>   line 82, in init_poolmanager
>       self.poolmanager = _AppEnginePoolManager(self._validate_certificate)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_toolbelt/adapters/appengine.py",
>   line 122, in **init**
>       validate_certificate=validate_certificate)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/appengine.py",
>   line 103, in **init**
>       "URLFetch is not available in this environment.")

Can someone helps me? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve the problem...

When I use this import:

```
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
appengine.monkeypatch()
```

All the http requests try to use URLFetch and it in GCE create problems.
Only **I need remove this two** lines and all works perfectly.

Thanks for your time! GDJ